VSCode autocomplete not suggesting deep nested import paths
I own a lib (Vite + TypeScript) which exports multiple components and icons. These can be resolved with imports from paths such as @myLib/button, @myLib/input and the likes.
I would now like to add a bunch of icons to the project so that they can be exported and easily imported by those using this lib. There are many icons and, as such, I would like to separate them into subfolders to be imported as @myLib/icons/status, @myLib/icons/arrows, @myLib/icons/misc and a few others.
My configurations to achieve this are as follows:
package.json
{
  // ...
  "exports": {
    "./icons/arrows": {
      "import": "./dist/Icons/arrows.esm.js",
      "types": "./dist/Icons/Arrows/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./icons/misc": {
      "import": "./dist/Icons/misc.esm.js",
      "types": "./dist/Icons/Misc/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./icons/status": {
      "import": "./dist/Icons/status.esm.js",
      "types": "./dist/Icons/Status/index.d.ts"
    }
  }
}

vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
    lib: {
      entry: {
        // ...
        button: "src/components/Button/index.tsx",
        "icons/arrows": "src/components/Icons/Arrows/index.tsx",
        "icons/misc": "src/components/Icons/Misc/index.tsx",
        "icons/status": "src/components/Icons/Status/index.tsx",
      },
    },
  },
});

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable",
      "ESNext",
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./src",
    "src/typings/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
# #     "src/stories/**/*",
    "**/*.test.tsx",
    "**/tests/**/*",
    "src/App.tsx",
    "src/main.tsx",
    "**/*Helper.tsx"
  ]
}

My project's folder structure is:
root
├── tsconfig.json
├── vite.config.ts
├── src
├──── components
├────── button 
├──────── index.tsx
├──────── Button.tsx
├────── icons
├──────── arrows
├────────── index.tsx
├────────── ArrowUpIcon.tsx
├────────── ArrowDownIcon.tsx
├──────── misc
├────────── index.tsx
├────────── CloseIcon.tsx
├────────── SettingsIcon.tsx
├──────── status
├────────── index.tsx
├────────── ErrorIcon.tsx
├────────── SuccessIcon.tsx

My build folder looks like this:
dist
├── Icons
├──── arrows.esm.js
├──── arrows.esm.js.map
├──── misc.esm.js
├──── misc.esm.js.map
├──── status.esm.js
├──── status.esm.js.map
├──── arrows
├────── index.d.tsx
├────── index.d.tsx.map
├────── ArrowUpIcon.d.tsx
├────── ArrowUpIcon.d.tsx.map
├────── ArrowDownIcon.d.tsx
├────── ArrowDownIcon.d.tsx.map
├──── misc
├────── index.d.tsx
├────── index.d.tsx.map
├────── CloseIcon.d.tsx
├────── CloseIcon.d.tsx.map
├────── SettingsIcon.d.tsx
├────── SettingsIcon.d.tsx.map
├──── status
├────── index.d.tsx
├────── index.d.tsx.map
├────── ErrorIcon.d.tsx
├────── ErrorIcon.d.tsx.map
├────── SuccessIcon.d.tsx
├────── SuccessIcon.d.tsx.map

Now, publishing the package and trying to use it from another project entirely, I get autocomplete for @myLib/input and @myLib/button as expected:

However, I do not get autocomplete for any of my icons export paths:

Typing it by hand however resolves the path successfully:

I am at a loss on how to get VSCode's intellisense to suggest these nested import paths. I tried to keep this example to a minimum but there many icons, which makes it not ideal to have them all exported from /icons/ directly.
What am I missing on my configs to make this work?
